# How to restart rxjs interval?

Tags: rxjs

I created a class which sets up a pausable RxJS `Observable` using the `interval` operator:

```
export class RepeatingServiceCall<T> {
  private paused = false;
  private observable: Observable<T>;
  constructor(serviceCall: () => Observable<T>, delay: number) {
    this.observable = interval(delay).pipe(flatMap(() => (!this.paused ? serviceCall() : NEVER)));
  }
  setPaused(paused: boolean) {
    this.paused = paused;
  }
  getObservable() {
    return observable;
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but the problem I am trying to solve is that I want the timer to reset when unpaused. So, let's say that the `interval` time is 10 seconds and 5 seconds after the last time the `interval` emitted, `setPaused(false)` is called. In that scenario, I want it to emit immediately and then restart the timer.

Would something like that be an easy thing to add?

Comment: do you want that immediate emission after unpause to happen only if certain time has passed or in any case when unpaused?

Comment: https://medium.com/js-in-action/rxjs-pause-and-resume-mighty-switchmap-41d0d1fe1113

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1542#issuecomment-202540367

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you use `timer` instead of `interval`, and set the initial delay to `0`, then your interval will fire immediately.

You can use `takeUntil` operator to prevent the interval to run always, and `repeat` operator with `delay` option (or `repeatWhen` for rxjs <7.0) to restart it whenever you want:

```js
import { Observable, Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { repeat, switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
export class RepeatingServiceCall<T> {
  readonly observable$: Observable<T>;
  private readonly _stop = new Subject<void>();
  private readonly _start = new Subject<void>();
    
  constructor(serviceCall: () => Observable<T>, delay: number) {
    this.observable$ = timer(0, delay)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => serviceCall()),
        takeUntil(this._stop),
        // repeatWhen(() => this._start) // for rxjs <7.0
        repeat({delay: () => this._start}) // for rxjs >7.0
      );
  }
  start(): void {
    this._start.next();
  }
  stop(): void {
    this._stop.next();
  }
}
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tbbb46?file=index.ts).

**P.S.:** Getters and setters are working different in typescript. So you do not need classic getter concept, you can just make the attribute `public` and `readonly`.

Comment: How does this work? I thought `takeUntil()` will complete the observable. So why does `repeatWhen()` restart it?

Comment: This is exactly what `repeatWhen` is for. Check the stackblitz example.

Comment: Oh I already have use cases for this. So many operators it's hard to know what they all do.

Comment: Did you try to press the start button more than once? It's a nice effect - why is this behavior?

Comment: @GreenEyedAndy because `repeatWhen` starts a new observable. You can put a boolean into start method to prevent that.

Comment: How to adapt this example to reset timer without using `_stop`?

Comment: @DurandA you just change `takeUntil` parameter with whatever ends your subscription. Or you can also change it with `takeWhile` pipe.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the behavior you are describing with the following snippet:

```js
const delay = 1000;

const playing = new BehaviorSubject(false);

const observable = playing.pipe(
  switchMap(e => !!e ? interval(delay).pipe(startWith('start')) : never())
);

observable.subscribe(e => console.log(e));

// play:
playing.next(true);

// pause:
playing.next(false);
```

- When the `playing` Observable emits `true`, the `switchMap` operator will return a new `interval` Observable.
- Use the `startWith` operator to emit an event immediately when unpausing.
- If you wish to have the interval start automatically when subscribing to the observable, then simply initialize the BehaviorSubject with `true`.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kxchvh?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach with a `switchMap`:

```js
const { fromEvent, timer } = rxjs;
const { takeUntil, switchMap, startWith } = rxjs.operators;

const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click');
const stop$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('stop'), 'click');


start$.pipe(
  startWith(void 0), // trigger emission at launch
  switchMap(() => timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    takeUntil(stop$)
  ))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```

And a simpler one, that `merge`s start and stop Observables to switch off them:

```js
const { fromEvent, merge, timer, NEVER } = rxjs;
const { distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, mapTo, startWith } = rxjs.operators;

const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click');
const stop$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('stop'), 'click');


merge(
  start$.pipe(mapTo(true), startWith(true)),
  stop$.pipe(mapTo(false))
).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(paused => paused ? timer(0, 1000) : NEVER)
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```

And another, even wierder approach, using `repeat()` :

```js
const { fromEvent, timer } = rxjs;
const { take, concatMap, takeUntil, repeat } = rxjs.operators;

const start$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click');
const stop$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('stop'), 'click');


start$.pipe(
  take(1),
  concatMap(()=>timer(0, 1000)),
  takeUntil(stop$),
  repeat()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```

*Just wanted to join this party :)*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [@s.alem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1784230/s-alem) 's answer, it really helped me.

From official documentation, `repeatWhen()` is deprecated in RxJs of v7 and will be removed in future version, and `repeat()` is a replacement of it.

So here's an updated version of @s.alem 's code:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pm5x2r?file=index.ts)

Basically the change is from

`repeatWhen(() => this._start),`

to

`repeat({ delay: (count) => this._start })`

Answer (score 0):

You can abandon the old timer on start and start a new one on start.

```js
const { interval, Subject, fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { takeUntil } = rxjs.operators;

let timer$;

const pause = new Subject();

const obs$ = new Subject();

obs$.subscribe(_ => { console.log('Timer fired') });

function start() {
  timer$ = interval(1000);
  timer$.pipe(takeUntil(pause)).subscribe(_ => { obs$.next(); });
}

function stop() {
  pause.next();
  timer$ = undefined;
}

fromEvent(document.getElementById('toggle'), 'click').subscribe(() => {
  if (timer$) {
    stop();
  } else {
    start();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">Start/Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```js
/**
* it is a simple timer created by via rxjs
* @author KentWood
* email minzojian@hotmail.com
*/
function rxjs_timer(interval, times, tickerCallback, doneCallback, startDelay) {
    this.pause = function () {
        this.paused = true;
    }
    this.resume = function () {
        this.paused = false;
    }
    this.stop = function () {
        if (this.obs) {
            this.obs.complete();
            this.obs.unsubscribe();
        }
        this.obs = null;

    }
    this.start = function (interval, times, tickerCallback, doneCallback, startDelay) {
        this.startDelay = startDelay || 0;
        this.interval = interval || 1000;
        this.times = times || Number.MAX_VALUE;
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.stop();

        rxjs.Observable.create((obs) => {
            this.obs = obs;
            let p = rxjs.timer(this.startDelay, this.interval).pipe(
                rxjs.operators.filter(() => (!this.paused)), 
              rxjs.operators.tap(() => {
                    if (this.currentTime++ >= this.times) {
                        this.stop();
                    }
                }),
              rxjs.operators.map(()=>(this.currentTime-1))
            );
            let sub = p.subscribe(val => obs.next(val), err => obs.error(err), () => obs
                .complete());
            return sub;
        }).subscribe(tickerCallback, null, doneCallback);
    }
    this.start(interval, times, tickerCallback, doneCallback, startDelay);
}
/////////////test/////////////
var mytimer = new rxjs_timer(
1000/*interval*/, 
10 /*times*/, 
(v) => {logout(`time:${v}`)}/*tick callback*/, 
() => {logout('done')}/*complete callback*/, 
2000/*start delay*/);

//call mytimer.pause() 
//call mytimer.resume() 
//call mytimer.stop() 




function logout(str){
  document.getElementById('log').insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin',`<p>${str}</p>`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>

<button onclick="mytimer.pause()"> pause</button>
<button onclick="mytimer.resume()"> resume</button>
<button onclick="mytimer.stop()"> stop</button>
<div id='log'></div>
```