# Reset Angular RXJS Timer On condition

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I have the following code

```
    public timePast:Observable<number>;
    private readonly _stop = new Subject<void>();
    private readonly _start = new Subject<void>();

    this.timePast = timer(1000, 1000).pipe(
            takeUntil(this._stop),
            repeatWhen(() => this._start)
        );

    this.timePast.subscribe(val =>
          {

            console.log(val);
              if(val>=sometime)
              {
                //reset timer
              }

          } );

start(): void {
    this._start.next();
  }
  stop(): void {
    this._stop.next();
  }
```

How do I reset the timer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart the timer on an rxjs interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716687/restart-the-timer-on-an-rxjs-interval)

Answer (score 0):

You can invert part of the logic for the start:

```
public timePast: Observable<number> = this._start.pipe(
  switchMap(() => timer(1000, 1000).pipe(takeUntil(this._stop)))
);
```