# matdialog appears empty when trying to pop it up at a certain time

Tags: angular

thanks in advance for your response. I am implementing an inactivity log out with three steps depending on the time of inactivity in my home component:

1- time starts at 15 seconds. (this works fine)
2- after 10 seconds of inactivity, the modal pops up--> isItTimeToShowPopUp() method (this is the only step where I have trouble)
3 - when the countdown is on one second, the session expires. (this works fine)

I'm having trouble when popping up a matdialog modal as it has a random behavior. The dialog component injected, appears empty, first, and then it appears with the correct message, after one second. Sometimes even it doesn't show the complete message, it appears empty. This is the only part that doesn't work correctly, and I have no idea why. Also, I'd appreciate any ideas on how could I make this work without having to write the same code in all the components of my app.

Here's my code:

dialogcomponent.html:

```html
<h1 matDialogTitle>Confirm</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <!-- {{confirmMessage}} -->

    <p [innerHTML]="confirmMessage"></p>

</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions class="pt-24">
    <button mat-raised-button class="mat-accent mr-16" (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">Confirm</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="dialogRef.close(false)">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

dialogcomponent.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'fuse-confirm-dialog',
    templateUrl: './confirm-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./confirm-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class FuseConfirmDialogComponent {
    public confirmMessage: string;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param {MatDialogRef<FuseConfirmDialogComponent>} dialogRef
     */
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FuseConfirmDialogComponent>
    ) {

    }

}
```

This component is injected in my home.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ProvisionedService } from '../../devices/provisioned-list/provisioned.service';
import { UsersService } from '../../users/users.service';
import { fromEvent, merge, interval, Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, take, skipWhile, takeLast, skipUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FuseConfirmDialogComponent } from "@fuse/components/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component";
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from "@angular/material";
import { StorageService } from '../../common/services/storage.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../common/services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  deviceList: DeviceModel[];
  devicesAlive: any;
  vanillaDevices: DeviceModel[];
  getDevicesInfoLoop: any;
  isAlive: any;
  invitationList: InvitationModel[];
  deviceId: any

  inactivityTime: number = 15;

  timeLapsedSinceInactivity: number = 0;
  seconds: number = this.padZero(0);
  subscription: Subscription;
  observeable$: Observable<any>;
  mergedObservable$: Observable<any>;
  event: Event;
  confirmDialogRef: MatDialogRef<FuseConfirmDialogComponent>;

  public inactivityTimerEvent: Array<any>[] = [[document, 'click'], [document, 'wheel'], [document, 'scroll'], [document, 'mousemove'],
   [document, 'keyup'], [window, 'resize'], [window, 'scroll'], [window, 'mousemove']];



  constructor(private provisionedService: ProvisionedService, private VanillaService: VanillaService, 
    private UsersService: UsersService, public _ngZone: NgZone,
    public _cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    public matDialog: MatDialog,
    public storageService: StorageService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  
    let observableArray$: Observable<any>[] = [];
    
    this.inactivityTimerEvent.forEach(x => {
      observableArray$.push(fromEvent(x[0], x[1]))
    })
    this.mergedObservable$ = merge(...observableArray$);

    this.startTimer(event);
   

  }

  public createObserable(): void {
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

      this.observeable$ = this.mergedObservable$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(ev => interval(1000).pipe(take      (this.inactivityTime))),

        tap(value => this.isItTimeToShowPopUp(value)),

        skipWhile((x) => {
          this.timeLapsedSinceInactivity = x;
          return x != this.inactivityTime - 1
        })
      );

      this.subscribeObservable();
    })

  }

  public isItTimeToShowPopUp(val: number) {
    let timeLeftForInactive = this.inactivityTime - val;
    if (timeLeftForInactive <= 15) {

      this.timeLapsedSinceInactivity = timeLeftForInactive;
      this.seconds = this.padZero(timeLeftForInactive % 15);
      this._cd.detectChanges();
      console.log(timeLeftForInactive);
    }

    if(timeLeftForInactive === 10) {
      this.confirmDialogRef = this.matDialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
        disableClose: false
      });
  
      this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage = "Your session is about to expire, please, press confirm to continue ";
  
      this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed()
        .subscribe(result => {
          if (result === true) {
           
            this.startTimer(event)
            this.unsubscribeObservable();
          }

          if (result === false) {
            this.authService.removeUserData();
            this.storageService.removelocalStorageData();
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        });
    }
    
    if(timeLeftForInactive === 1) {
      this.authService.removeUserData();
      this.storageService.removelocalStorageData();
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);

    }
    }



  public subscribeObservable() {
    this.subscription = this.observeable$.subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(`subscribed for ${x + 1} sec`);
      this.unsubscribeObservable()
    })
  }
  public padZero(digit: any) {
    return digit <= 9 ? '0' + digit : digit;
  }

  public unsubscribeObservable() {
    console.log('  unsubscriebd')
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  public startTimer($event) {
    this.createObserable();
    console.log('subscription started');
  }
  public stopTimer(event) {
    if (this.subscription && !this.subscription.closed) {
      this.seconds = this.padZero(0);
      this.unsubscribeObservable();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would explicitly pass the data you wish to show (confirmMessage) with the dialogConfig that you pass to the .open() method.

```
 this.confirmDialogRef = this.matDialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
    disableClose: false,
    confirmMessage: 'Your session is about to expire'
  });
```

In your dialog, you can reference the data via a DI variable :

```
 constructor(...,  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
      this.confirmMessage = data.confirmMessage;
 }
```

[Here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/) is a guide that includes some info about dialogs in a step by step fashion, and of course [Mat-Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) has a section for MatDialogConfig.

Comment: I thought it could be involving the order in which the message is declared, but if I were you I'd slap a debugger; statement inside of the if(timeLeftForInactive === 10) block or inside the dialogComponents ngOnInit to see what's going on. 

Also while digging through some online stuff I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716687/restart-the-timer-on-an-rxjs-interval
it sorta seems like a more elegant way to deal with timer resets, which COULD be where the problem lies, but I'm not 100% sure.

post back if you get it working/see some weird stuff in the debugger!